# Name of a certain type of rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

What is the name given to (if there exists any) commutative rings $R$ with identity such that $R/(a)$ is finite for every non-zero $a\in R$

Thanks a lot

Comment: They certainly exist (see $\mathbb{Z}$, or any finite ring), but I don't know of any name.

Comment: Equivalently, $R/I$ is finite, for all ideals $I\ne 0$.

Comment: @MattPressland Sure. $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field is another example. I believe any euclidean domain as well.

Comment: Residually finite.

Comment: I don't think they've received special attention, unlike residually finite groups. The larger class of rings of Krull dimension 1 have been widely studied.

Comment: According to this question, such rings must be integral domains:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126206/prove-that-an-infinite-ring-with-finite-quotient-rings-is-an-integral-domain

Comment: Pete L. Clark discusses them briefly in the first few pages of  his [notes on factorization](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/factorization.pdf) - see his discussion of *finite norm* rings. This is a bit of folklore that has not yet made it into common textbooks (though I vaguely recall it appearing as an exercise somewhere).