# Infinite ring is an integral domain if the quotient with each non-trivial ideal is finite

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity of infinite cardinality. If for every non-zero  ideal $I$ of $R$ we have $|\frac{R}{I}|<\infty$ then $R$ is an integral domain. How do I go on proving this?

Comment: By "proper" you also mean to include "nonzero" apparently? "Proper" typically means "not the whole ring."

Comment: This might be of some help: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1446472429

Comment: rschwieb, yes non-zero. as otherwise the condition can never be satisfied for |R/(0)| = |R| = infinity

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126206.

Comment: Minseon Shin Thank you! I couldn't find this post when I was writing it unfortunately...